# php multiple select query in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have this php code, i have 3 tables and i want to search in all of them

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cloth_eng 
              UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_gbc` 
              UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_pcv`
              WHERE CONCAT(`supplier_prefix`, `supplier_name`, `stock_id`, `category`, `description`, `yield`, `size`, `color`, `usage_type`, `remarks`) 
              LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
else 
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_eng` UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_gbc` UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_pcv`";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

function filterTable($query)
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "redanura1");
        $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        return $filter_result;
    }
```

please help me with this, it keeps on displaying the data in the first 2 tables it doesn't filter

Comment: You should provide more context. What do you want to search? Is it in some variables? What database fields should it search in? How is it related to the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` joins the previous queries results, you need the `where` on each `select`. You also should parameterize this query and look at using full text indexing. So:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cloth_eng WHERE CONCAT(`supplier_prefix`, `supplier_name`, `stock_id`, `category`, `description`, `yield`, `size`, `color`, `usage_type`, `remarks`) 
          LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')
          UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_gbc` WHERE CONCAT(`supplier_prefix`, `supplier_name`, `stock_id`, `category`, `description`, `yield`, `size`, `color`, `usage_type`, `remarks`) 
          LIKE concat('%', ?, '%') 
          UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl_cloth_pcv`
          WHERE CONCAT(`supplier_prefix`, `supplier_name`, `stock_id`, `category`, `description`, `yield`, `size`, `color`, `usage_type`, `remarks`) 
          LIKE concat('%', ?, '%');
```

and then bind `$valueToSearch` 3 times.

Comment: What do you mean bind $valueToSearch 3 times? I dont know how to do that. And where do i put the $valueToSearch in the query?

Comment: That's what the binding does. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Your `filterTable` is insecure, you should pass in a second parameter which has values to be bound.